# Visual Studio 2012 Docked Window Tab Order

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 has the same window/toolbar docking/auto-hiding feature as 2010, but I noticed that the tabs don't stay in order anymore if you use the pin then unpin them.  This kind of defeats the purpose of docking windows/toolbars for me, since I put them where I'll remember where they are.  If they keep changing order, I have to stop and search for the one I want, rather than them just staying in the order I put them in.  Does anyone know of a way to keep them in an order?

Comment: I have a similar issue ... every time I start VS2012 I get the same three open files and they are not the ones I was working on last time I closed.  I think it is a cache issue but have not yet found where to reset the VS2012 cache for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn off an option "Auto Hide button affects active tool windows only", the tab order doesn't change because the whole window is pinned. But you cannot pin a specific tab on this setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx